# Invalid sim card/no sim card inserted error

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sim-card, lg-g3

So I will do my best to explain what's been happening and what I have attempted to fix the issue.  First off, I have a g3 us990 under US Cellular running octos marshmallow (custom ROM) along with TWRP and have been for well over a year.

Last week I noticed I had no signal in my phone and a message on the lock screen saying invalid card.  I have been able to temporarily fix it anywhere from 30 mins to a day where it then would stop and show the message again and texting/calling would stop working.  I have tried restarting it(random if it would fix it or not), reinserting the sim card(found sometimes the no sim card is inserted error would show up), factory resetting(same as restarting), restoring from a back up(still nothing), and I have even went out and got a new sim card and activated it to see if that was it.

My next plan of action is to restore back to stock using the LG flash tool.  But I feel that won't work either.  Another idea of mine was purchasing a new sim card reader off eBay and doing some soldering, but I want that to be a last resort.

So at this point I am thinking it is the sim card reader in some way, but I would figure that if it was the sim card reader, it wouldn't work at all.  I'm hoping someone that has had experience with this before knows a fix or any other ideas on what to do because I am just about out of them.

Comment: I had this issue around the same time.  Did yours also progress into the full boot loop issue like mine did, and [this link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/help/lg-g3-d850-sim-card-removed-problem-t3387792) hints may be typical??

Comment: @JeopardyTempest I eventually got a new phone,  but if it helps, I think my phone has more of an internal problem because it would randomly shut off and not turn back on unless i take the battery out.

Comment: Likewise, and sounds like that's a pretty central theme of the boot loop.  I was pretty convinced it was internal hardware (like the board), but now who knows.  Will post back for the benefit of any others if I sort it out :-)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest please do, I still have the phone and If someone finds a way to fix this sort of issue, that would be awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

check if sim card is inserted probably, been having same issue. the metal pins should be properly in contact with the gold part on the sim.

Comment: that's the thing, the sim card only goes in one ways and it has to slide all the way into the slot in order put the battery in